# How do I 'await' information from a modal?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a codesandbox for this question: https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-modal-input-forked-jelhlr?file=/src/App.jsx

I want to get the filename via the modal, and when the user **completes** that action, I want to do stuff with that information, in this case I want to make an api request.

Thanks!
EDIT:
I have a form with the following onSubmit:

```
// 1. prepare data for POST request
const data=prepareData();
// 2. get title for data entry from user
onOpen();
// 3. send data via POST request
const response=await axios.post('route',{title,data})
```

The way things are, the modal shows at step 2 and without waiting for user input, step 3 occurs. I want to get the title name from the user and **then** I want step 3 to occur.

Comment: Correct me if my understanding is wrong. Your model has an input field and you can read the value from an event like `event.target.value`. What's the need of `await` here?
You can make an API call when the user clicks the save button since you already storing the data in the state.

Comment: @mchowdam I've done a poor job on the codesandbox. Let me see if I can simply what I'm trying to do. I have a form with the following onSubmit:
```
// 1. prepare data for POST request
const data=prepareData();
// 2. get title for data entry from user
onOpen();
// 3. send data via POST request
const response=await axios.post('route',{title,data})
```
The way things are, the modal shows at step 2 and without waiting for user input, step 3 occurs. I want to get the title name from the user and **then** I want step 3 to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the package [react-modal-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-promise) that does exact this. Works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

The value of the textbook is saved into the ref `titleInputRef`.

This means you can access the value of the ref/textbox with the following:

```js
titleInputRef.current.value
```

To log the value to the console, for example:

```js
console.log(titleInputRef.current.value)
```